# How to count amount of columns in sqlite from command line tool

Tags: database, sqlite

I am trying to count the columns from a sqlite db using the sqlite command line tool. To test it I created a sample db like this:

```
c:\>sqlite.exe mydb.sqlite "create table tbl1(one varchar(10), two smallint);"
```

Now lets say i don't know that the table tbl1 has 2 columns, **how can I find that using a query from the command line tool?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run:

```
pragma table_info(yourTableName)
```

See:

```
http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info
```

for more details.

Comment: But is there a way to just display a number that represents the number of columns? I need this because the command line tool will be run from an installer so I don't want to have to parse or do any extra step because it wont be so easy from the installer, i just want the columns number.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no direct way to get the column count. I would suggest one of the following:

1. run the previous query and use the number of results returned as your count. or 

2. Add your own meta-data table that already has the number of columns in it. Then you can query directly from that table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way I found useful under Linux. Create a bash script file `columns.sh` and ensure it has execute permissions and copy - paste the following code.

`columns() { for table in $(echo ".tables" | sqlite3 $1); do echo "$table    $(echo "PRAGMA table_info($table);" | sqlite3 $1 | wc -l)"; done ;}`

Type the following command, in terminal, on the first line to return results

```
 $  columns <database name>
    <table1>          <# of columns>
    <table2>          <# of columns>
```

Note: Ensure database is not corrupted or encrypted.

source: http://www.quora.com/SQLite/How-can-I-count-the-number-of-columns-in-a-table-from-the-shell-in-SQLite

**UPDATE**

Here is an interesting URL for Python Script Solution

http://pagehalffull.wordpress.com/2012/11/14/python-script-to-count-tables-columns-and-rows-in-sqlite-database/

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pragma_table_info(tablename);
```